# how can I add ajax gif image while sending request to server and get response in django with dajaxice?

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

this is my template(profile.html):

```
<input id="postButton"type="button" value="share" onclick="Dajaxice.social.dajaxice_example(my_callback)" />
```

here is my ajax.py :

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from social.models import *                       # my database


@dajaxice_register
def dajaxice_example(request):
    user = User.objects.get(email="email@domain.com")
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':user.firstName})
```

and here is my javascript code that alert the page :

```
function my_callback(data){
    alert(data.message);
}
```

when I click the button i must waiting for response from database that find the `User` that its `email` is `example@domain.com` how can I insert some funny gif ajax image for showing to user that process is running.thanks

EDIT:
I also add this lines to template and javascript file but `ajaxStart` seems that doesn't work:

```
<div id="wait" style="display:none;"><img src={% static 'social/img/ajax.gif' %} /><br>Loading..</div>
```

and in js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display","block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display","none");
  });
});
```

Comment: Only add an `$.ajaxSetup`

Comment: where I must add it ?

Comment: At the beginning of the `js` or also you can add an `ajaxSend`

Comment: I add `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` but don't work in browser.